# Joining dataframes in panda problem with special characters

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two CSV-files:

"inventory.csv" with columns *'Code', ... , 'Sum(Quantity)'*

"sales.csv" with columns *'Code', -many other columns-*

the column 'Code' from sales contains a certain productcode (a string)

for example: '6ES7 122-1BB10-0AA0'

each 'Code' from sales.csv exists in inventory.csv (which is not true the other way around)

My goal is to make a dataframe with the following columns:

'Code', 'Sum(Quantity)', -many other colums-

I have written some code that somewhat achieves this (shown below) but it returns the following error:

IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

**part of sales.csv:**

Code; ... ; ... ; 'Sum(Quantity)'

> ...
>
> SSD 2.5" 32GB SATA III;Onbekend;SSD;4;
>
> 6SE7018-0EP50-Z (Z=C23+F01+G91);Siemens;Masterdrive MC;4;
>
> QS30LLPCQ;Banner;3071378;4;
>
> 6ES5 318-8MB12;Siemens;Interface Module : ET200U;4;
>
> ...

**part of inventory.csv:**

Code; -many other columns-

> ...
>
> 6SE7018-0EP50-Z;Siemens;Masterdrive MC;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;1;
>
> 6SE7018-0EP50-Z (Z=C23+F01+G91);Siemens;Masterdrive MC;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;
>
> 6SE7018-0EP50-Z (Z=L20);Siemens;Masterdrive MC;0;0;1;0;0;0;0;0;
>
> 6SE7018-0EP60;Siemens;Masterdrive VC;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;0;
>
> ...

The error occurs when searching for '6SE7018-0EP50-Z (Z=C23+F01+G91)' in inventory.csv so I guess it is because one of the following signs: ()+=

The code that I used is below:

```
import pandas as pd

filename_sales = "sales.csv"
filename_inv = "inventory.csv"

df_sales = pd.read_csv(filename_sales, sep=';')
df_inv = pd.read_csv(filename_inv, sep=';')

#throws away unneeded columns
df_sales = df_sales[["Code","Sum(Quantity)"]]
df_inv = df_inv.drop(['Brand Name', 'Name'], axis=1)

df_out = pd.DataFrame()


for index, row in df_sales.iterrows():
   temp = df_inv[df_inv['Code'].str.contains(row["Code"])].iloc[0] 
   temp["Sum(Quantity)"] = row['Sum(Quantity)']
   df_out = df_out.append(temp)

print(df_out)
```

- How could I avoid/solve this error?
- Is this the appropriate way to join these df's into what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend joining the two tables using [df.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), then you can join the two dataframes like you would sql tables.

Make sure you join on='Code'. You can specify either a left or inner join, and then you can avoid messy, painful, slow iterations with the pandas dfs.

For example:

```
df_sales = df_sales[["Code","Sum(Quantity)"]]
df_inv = df_inv.drop(['Brand Name', 'Name'], axis=1)
#once you make sure you have the columns you want, go ahead and join them

df_sales = df_sales.merge(df_inv, how='left', on='Code')
```

Comment: Perfectly solved my problem and increases readability and efficiency, thanks a lot!

Comment: @SvenOnderbeke I'm glad that solved the problem. If you're happy with it, feel free to formally mark my response as one that answered your button (it will mark it with a green check mark) and to upvote my response